# Before setting JLabel's Clip with a shape (polygon) getClip() still return null

Tags: graphics, null, jlabel, clip

In my program I try to set the Clip of a JLabel like this:

```
JLabel  jl = new JLabel();
jl.setVisible(true);
jl.setSize( 50, 50);
componentWhereIPutEverything.add( jl);
jl.setLocation( 50 , 50);

int xx[] = { (int) UpLeft.getX(), (int) UpRigth.getX(), (int) BottomRigth.getX(), (int) BottomLeft.getX()   };
int yy[] = { (int) UpLeft.getY(), (int) UpRigth.getY(), (int) BottomRigth.getY(), (int)  BottomLeft.getY()  };
Polygon poly = new Polygon(xx, yy, xx.length);
jlabel.getGraphics().setClip( poly );
```

After this, i try:

```
jl.getGraphics().getClip()
```

and it returns null.
How can I fix it? Where are the errors?
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you set the clip on one graphics object doesn't mean that it will be there for all graphics objects. Your best solution is to override getGraphics() and add your setClip in there

`public Graphics getGraphics() {
  Graphics g = super.getGraphics();
  g.setClip(...);
  return g;
}`

Comment: i'm sorry, i've make a mistake : i wrote      jlabel.getGraphics().setClip( poly );
instead of
    jl.getGraphics().setClip( poly );
Then, is my code still wrong ?
Thank you for your patience